# Integrate a function inside square limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I wanted to integrate $f(r)=4+r^2$ inside a square of side length $a$, where $r$ is the distance from the origin of coordinates.

I can't figure out the limits of my integral. Can I get some help?

Comment: Where is your square located? What are the coordinates of its vertices?

Comment: The square is centered on the origin with the sides parallel to the axes.

Comment: Can you determine the coordinates of the vertices?

Comment: (a/2,a/2) , (-a/2,a/2), (-a/2,-a/2), (a/2,-a/2)

Comment: Can you use these to determine the limits of integration? You need $x$ to range over all possible $x$ values and $y$ to range over all possible $y$ values of points in your square.

Comment: In this case I should change r as a function of x and y, right?

Comment: Yes: $r^2=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: As easy as that then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Result $\ds{= 4a^{2} + \iint_{\mathsf{square}}r^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y}$

\begin{align}
\iint_{\mathsf{square}}r^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y & =
4\int_{0}^{a/2}\int_{0}^{a/2}\pars{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y =
8\int_{0}^{a/2}\int_{0}^{a/2}x^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y =
8\,{a^{3} \over 24}\,{a \over 2}
\\[5mm] &
\mbox{Result} = \bbx{\ds{4a^{2} + {1 \over 6}\,a^{4}}}
\end{align}